# Authenticating requests across microservices

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js, microservices

I have a bunch of microservices, one of them is responsible for authenticating a user. In this service, a user is allowed to login with facebook, google (with Passportjs) and use a regular username/password login.

Passport makes it very easy to authenticate requests to an API and deal with sessions, however if I have multiple API's (due to multiple microservices). Passport will probably cause a lot of overhead because I would have to copy all the passport configuration files to all the services and I'd have to change them all if I want to change something. Are there are any other options? I thought of using JWT with a shared secret across all the services but then again I'm not sure if this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

One of the more useful approaches here is to use an API gateway which essentially means that all user facing microservices should be registered on it and routes to internal microservices. The service that you're using for authentication which also happens to use third party can still exist as is but would live behind the API gateway.

Once the user is logged in, any other endpoint will check the user sessions with the service that you're using to authenticate the users whether its Facebook, Google, etc before sending the request downstream to other microservices. Note here that the other microservices that required the authentication or authorization needs to be private and only reachable from services within the same network such as the API gateway.